# How to use the control of Textbox in .cs file of WPF Project?

Tags: c#, wpf

When I try to use the `TextBox` control, there is an error. Why can't I use the control by its name directly, and how do I fix the error?

```xml
<TextBox  x:Name="receiveTextBox"  Foreground="White" Background="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap"  TextAlignment="Left"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="15" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
         receiveTextBox.Text(" hello  ");  // <------- this's error part !
```

Comment: please update your sample code

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 2):

Text isn't a method - it's a property.

```
receiveTextBox.Text = " hello  ";
```

In the future, make sure you also tell us what error message you're seeing (and also format your code).